# How I can know which icon theme is being used in Ubuntu for a file explorer project

Tags: unity, themes, icons

I made a simple text-based file manager in python for fun (very simple, just for copying and pasting files, and viewing them).

Now I'm planning to implement a simple GUI. My idea is to show all the directories and files graphically, so I looked for the default icons, but I don't know how to control if the user is using a different theme, and if so, to get the path to the images. Is it possible?